# Flask-Appbuilder can not connect phpmyadmin

Tags: flask, phpmyadmin, openldap, flask-appbuilder

I already installed python ldap in my web server

```
(venv) vocstartsoft:~/environment/myproject $ pip install python-ldap
Requirement already satisfied: python-ldap in ./venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-ldap) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.3.7 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-ldap) (0.4.8)
```

I add code to config.py

```
import ldap
AUTH_TYPE = 2
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER="ldap://my public address:389"
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS=False
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "123"
AUTH_LDAP_APPEND_DOMAIN ="example.com"
```

I use phpmyadmin for openldap:

- Login DN:cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
- password:123

Than I login my webpage:
Invalid login. Please try again.

- user:admin
- password:123

Comment: None of the configuration or pip commands you've posted have anything to do with phpMyAdmin. It's a tool for administrators to manage MySQL or MariaDB databases and has nothing to do with LDAP. I'm not sure how you're trying to use phpMyAdmin to connect directly to LDAP or what result you expect, but this isn't making a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply my question, Do you have any solution? I just want to create new user in ldap server to login my web page